# Python Blender convert Curve to Mesh

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender, bpy

How could I convert Curve to Mesh. I want to import SVG and convert it to 3D object automatically. All what i found how to import `bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath="")`

When I try to select all curves and convert to MESH i got error
`RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.convert.poll() failed, context is incorrect`

Answer (score 1):

I found how to fix this error:

just need to select object correctly
`bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[0]`
and after that convert to MESH

```
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
```